# Wordpress: Style Post_Format loop-single.php using get_template_part?

Tags: wordpress, templates, post, loops, format

I pretty much just want to remove the post metadata from the Gallery Posts.

**Here is my index.php//**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
  <div id="right-content">
     <?php get_template_part( 'loop', get_post_format() ); ?>
  </div>

<div id="left-content">
  <div class="inner"> 
  <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
  </div> 
</div>
```

**Here is my single.php//**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="main-content">     
<?php get_template_part( 'loop', 'single' ); ?>
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

What I don't understand is how to set up the loop or loop-single files in order to get separate templates for the standard and gallery single posts.

I have added a loop and loop-single.php file.

**Here are pastebins of those files//**

http://pastebin.com/9xSZKnJA  - loop.php

http://pastebin.com/WiXwKf7d  - loop-single.php

## **EDIT//**

Here are the new "single-gallery.php" and "loop-gallery.php" files inside this pastebin//
http://pastebin.com/YukyZ9hm

Comment: what do you mean by "removing post metadata"?

Comment: The area that says "Filed under" "Posted By" and lists tags or categories. I'll edit the post to show you what I meant. @doublesharp

Comment: That's probably in your `sidebar.php` - it usually defaults to showing some info including metadata if you don't have any widgets set up.

Comment: @doublesharp No, not at all. I don't have meta data inside any of my sidebars. The pastebins show where it's located...

Comment: That's what I was saying - the `loop` files are only used for pages that show "The Loop", and aren't used on your single pages. You need to look at the template for `page.php` or `single.php`, which often show that info via the sidebar.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a different template for different types, you will need to create a template for each post type. Assuming that you are using the `gallery` type, you would want to copy the contents of `single.php` to a file called `single-gallery.php` and change the loop template part to be `get_template_part( 'loop', 'gallery' );`. You would then copy `loop-single.php` to a file called `loop-gallery.php` and modify its contents as desired.

You can find more info on theme development here http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Comment: Ok, so that's definitely not it (unless you have the meta data widget added). You should take a look at the contents of `page.php` or `single.php`

Comment: check out a couple pages from my site, one is a news post : http://keihead.com/test/dfgdfgdfgd  another is a gallery post : http://keihead.com/test/album3  scroll to the bottom of the gallery post and you will still see the "Filed Under" text :(

Comment: I have the news page that displays the standard posts assigned to a news.php (template) and the page that displays the gallery posts have a photos.php (template) I just checked in the page.php file and there is no meta data inside.

Comment: What is the content of your news.php file?

Comment: If you take a look at the original post I listed the "single.php" contents there... **NEWS.PHP** http://pastebin.com/6ifeKPju

Comment: have to run, but I made a type in my answer, should be named `single-<post-type>.php`, so `single-gallery.php`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Still no luck though :'( @doublesharp